# Array of keys, find values in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have an array which has the keys, I need to find inside a json array of objects.

my array:

`arr= ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr']`

d.data format:

```
[{'abc': 123, 'xyz': 321, 'pqr': 345}, {'abc': 111, 'xyz': 222, 'pqr': 333}.....]
```

I have a json object.

arr is a list of keys and I need to find their values inside the json array of objects.

I have a huge array (arr) which is why I don't want to hard code it.

I have tried to do:

```
arr.forEach(x => {
   let valss = d.data.map(structure => Object.values(structure.x));
});
```

I am getting an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

How can I the values for the keys inside my array?

Comment: can you add example of result you are looking for this method ?

Comment: I want to get values from d.data using the keys in the array

Comment: are you expecting something like `[[123, 321, 345], [111, 222, 333],...]` ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON, the tags and all references should be removed (just globally remove "json").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
for(var j = 0; d.data.length; j++){
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let valss = d.data[j][arr[i]]
  }
}
```

Provided your data sample, all you need to do is loop through each object in the dictionary, then loop through your keys to get the keys in the dictionary. Giving you the values you would expect.

Comment: @noob I have added a change for the data structure you gave. Loop through each object in the array and then loop through each item in the dictionary based on the key

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

All values in one result array:

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'];
var data = [{'abc': 123, 'xyz': 321, 'pqr': 345}, {'abc': 111, 'xyz': 222, 'pqr': 333}];
var result = [];

for(let item of data) {
  arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
    if(item.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
      result.push(item[el]);
    }
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Or separate sub arrays for each object in the data array:

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'];
var data = [{'abc': 123, 'xyz': 321, 'pqr': 345}, {'abc': 111, 'xyz': 222, 'pqr': 333}];
var result = [];

for(let item of data) {
  var temp = [];
  arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
    if(item.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
      temp.push(item[el]);
    }
  });
  
  if(temp.length > 0) {
    result.push(temp);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values of the objects in the `data` array, you can simply map through it and return just the values. Like this: `data.map((o) => Object.values(o));`

```js
let arr = ["abc", "xyz", "pqr"];

let data = [
  { abc: 123, xyz: 321, pqr: 345 },
  { abc: 111, xyz: 222, pqr: 333 },
];

let values = data.map((o) => Object.values(o));

console.log(values) // [ [ 123, 321, 345 ], [ 111, 222, 333 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```js
var arr= ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr']
var data = [{'abc': 123, 'xyz': 321, 'pqr': 345}, {'abc': 111, 'xyz': 222, 'pqr': 333}]
var values = arr.map( key => {
  let vals = data.map( val => {
    return val[key]
   })
  return vals
})
console.log(values)
```